# trying to get mythmote to work on mythbuntu

Tags: mythbuntu, mythtv

I know I need to change to a static ip address but every way I find won't work.I found instructions to use gui but I don't have the icon that's used and I tried the command line but "cd/etc/network" gives me the message no such file.where to I go from here? please keep it simple I'm new to mythbuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Run `nm-connection-editor` in the frontend machine. Edit the connection you use. In IPv4 or IPv6 tab choose manual method. Add address: Choose IP that is outside of range used by DHCP of your router, use 255.255.255.0 as netmask and your router's IP as Gateway. Save and reboot.

Don't forget to enable "Enable Network Remote Control interface" setting in Setup->General of the frontend.